# Consulta SQL ,Necesito Ayuda

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ejercicio: Mostrar la Cantidad Enviada por dia para el mes de noviembre de 1996

Tablas Necesarias

```
OrderDetails(OrderID,ProductID,Quantity)
Orders(OrderID,OrderDate)
```

No se como hacer para que el Count(Quantity) que me cuenta la cantidad en noviembre del 1996, lo haga por dia...

```
SELECT Count(OD.Quantity)
FROM OrderDetails OD,Orders O
WHERE OD.OrderID=O.OrderID and
O.OrderDate >='01/11/1996' AND O.OrderDate<='29/11/1996'
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba agrupando por fechas, y haciendo suma de la cantidad (*Count* lo que hace es contar el número de veces que tenemos valores en Quantity), en este caso se haría de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT SUM(OD.Quantity)
FROM OrderDetails OD,Orders O
WHERE OD.OrderID=O.OrderID and
O.OrderDate >='01/11/1996' AND O.OrderDate<='29/11/1996'
GROUP BY O.OrderDate
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, sin embargo me parece que el O.P. requiere usar `COUNT` y tu le sugieres que use otro método. Sería recomendable que le pidieras aclaración al O.P. sobre su requerimiento antes de responder. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras creo que Juan está en lo correcto al usar SUM() en vez de COUNT() debido a que se está agrupando una columna de cantidad. Por otro lado, creo que faltó incluir la columna de la fecha en el listado de columnas para que sea más claro lo que está haciendo.

Comment: @LuisCazares, nunca he dicho que esté incorrecto, solo que en la pregunta el O.P. no indica si se puede usar otro método aparte de COUNT. Al parecer es un ejercicio académico y tal vez la finalidad del mismo es resolver un problema usando COUNT. Si el O.P. no aclara eso, tal vez no es prudente dar una respuesta aunque sea correcta en términos generales. El problema es que la pregunta no deja claro exactamente el requerimiento. Saludos